# When is useful to use delegate type in a web application

Tags: c#, architecture, delegates

I use C# and Asp.Net Web Forms.

I read about the way Asp.Net deal with events for the GUI Objects using its "Delegate Model".

I'm concerting if would make sense use "Custom Delegate Type" in other context a part of event handling.

My questions:

- In a real world scenario when could be useful to use Delegate Types apart from event handling? Example: for validation fields in a class?
- In which kind of architecture Custom Delegate Type best feet?
- Pro and Cons of Delegate Type?

Thanks for your time on this!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- If you use LINQ to Objects at all, you're using delegates. (If you're using EF or something similar, then you're using expression trees of delegate types.)
- If you use MVC, you're probably using expression trees too (`@Html.For(x => ...)`)
- If you ever start threads or tasks, you'll be using delegates.

Basically they're great for representing single operations in an easily-expressible way. They can be used as an alternative to single-method interfaces, and work well for providing hooks for custom behaviour instead of using inheritance.

Since .NET 3.5 with its `Action` and `Func` delegate families, I rarely create custom delegate types - only when it makes sense to do so on readability grounds, basically.

Comment: @Html.For is expression tree - it parses it to figure out intent

Comment: Thanks Jon for your comment on this!